# Haskell: finding tuples of elements that equal n

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function in Haskell that takes a list of integers and an integer n and finds all tuples that equal n. So far I have an implementation that works

```
tuplesum :: (Eq b, Num b) => [b] -> b -> [(b, b)]
tuplesum xs n = [(x1,x2) | x1 <- xs, x2 <- xs, x1 + x2 == n, x1 <= x2]
```

so if I gave this function the input

```
tuplesum [5,1,4,0,5,6,9] 10
```

the output is
    `[(5,5),(5,5),(1,9),(4,6),(5,5),(5,5)]`
However, I have 4 duplicates of the (5,5) solution. I would like the function to output `[(5,5),(1,9),(4,6)]`but I cant figure out how to constrain tuples that have the same integers without removing it as a solution entirely.

Comment: should `x1 <= x2`, or was this just an attempt to perform *symmetry breaking*.

Comment: try `nub` from Data.List.

Comment: yes, I am trying to avoid the repeated symmetric solution

Comment: btw: With imperative programming there is an *O(n log n)* algorithm which does this. Yours is *O(n^2)*.

Comment: @Elmex80s: in Haskell as well, given we use `HashSet`s (and hashsets *can* be implemented in *pure* functional programming).

Comment: @Elmex80s why do you think that has anything to do with imperative programming? You can sort and scan from both ends in O(n log n) time without ever involving imperative programming.

Answer (score 6):

## Symmetry breaking in tuple generation

I have the impression that you are looking for a way to select two elements out of the list such that `x1` is always located *before* `x2`.

A common way to always let `x2` iterate over the remainder of the list is by using [**`tails :: [a] -> [[a]]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:tails). For a list, `tails` will generate a list of all tails of the list, starting with the list itself. For example:

```
Prelude Data.List> tails [1, 4, 2, 5]
[[1,4,2,5],[4,2,5],[2,5],[5],[]]
```

We can use this with pattern matching to select one element, and get a reference to the remaining element. For example:

```
import Data.List(tails)

tuplesum :: (Eq b, Num b) => [b] -> b -> [(b, b)]
tuplesum xs n = [(x1,x2) | (x1:x2s) <- tails xs, x2 <- x2s, x1 + x2 == n]
```

Note that it is still possible to obtain duplicates here, for example if `5` would occur three times in the list, since in that case `x1` can select the first `5`, and then `x2` can select the second `5` as well as the last one. We can make use of a uniqness filter like [**`nub :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub) for this:

```
import Data.List(nub, tails)

tuplesum :: (Eq b, Num b) => [b] -> b -> [(b, b)]
tuplesum xs n = nub [(x1,x2) | (x1:x2s) <- tails xs, x2 <- x2s, x1 + x2 == n]
```

Note that it is however still better to use `tails` here, since it will increase performance, since we will simply generate a smaller amount of duplicates in the first place.

## Using a hashset to obtain the "other" element

The above algorithm is still *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*, and not very fast. We can however solve the problem the other way around: we can first construct a `HashSet` of the elements, and the for each element `x1`, check if `n - x1` is a member, like:

```
import Data.Hashable(Hashable)
import Data.HashSet(fromList, member)

tuplesum :: (Ord b, Hashable b, Num b) => [b] -> b -> [(b, b)]
tuplesum xs n = nub [(x1,x2) | x1 <- xs, let x2 = n-x1, x1 <= x2, member x2 hs]
    where hs = fromList xs
```

But the runtime is still *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* because of the `nub`, we can however use a [**`hashNub :: (Eq a, Hashable a) => [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/universum-0.9.0/docs/src/Nub.html#hashNub) here:

> ```
> hashNub :: (Eq a, Hashable a) => [a] -> [a]
> hashNub = go HashSet.empty
>   where
>     go _ []     = []
>     go s (x:xs) =
>       if x `HashSet.member` s
>       then go s xs
>       else x : go (HashSet.insert x s) xs
> ```

and then let it work with:

```
import Data.Hashable(Hashable)
import Data.HashSet(fromList, member)

tuplesum :: (Ord b, Hashable b, Num b) => [b] -> b -> [(b, b)]
tuplesum xs n = hashNub [(x1,x2) | x1 <- xs, let x2 = n-x1, x1 <= x2, member x2 hs]
    where hs = fromList xs
```

Now it works in *O(n log n)*.

Comment: Is `tails` supposed to be applied to `xs`?

Comment: @4castle: yes, since then we iterate over the list of tails (but it starts with the full list) so we can pattern match an element `x1`, and `x2s` is the list of remaining elements.

Answer (score 0):

I just really liked your function `tuplesum xs n = [(x1,x2) | x1 <- xs, x2 <- xs, x1 + x2 == n, x1 <= x2]` because it is a Cartesian product and it eliminates most symmetrical pairs that would otherwise constitute about half. It gets the predicate matches so very well. The only problem remaining is the duplicate elements. I had forgotten about this until recently and Pg. 86 of  **Graham Hutton**'s **"Programming in Haskell"** and his `rmdups` function. What I like about his `rmdups` is that it neither depends on imports.

```
rmdups :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
rmdups [] = []
rmdups (x:xs) = x : filter (/= x) (rmdups xs)
```

Hutton's solution is wonderfully general and classically recursive. I did not want to post his solution here without adding something original so here is a list comprehension to eliminate duplicates of any data type including tuples.

```
rmdups ls = [d|(z,d)<- zip [0..] ls, notElem d $ take z ls]
```

You can place either `rmdups` function in front of your function `rmdups.tuplesum`
Your function eliminates most symmetrical pairs so `rmdups` does not.

```
rmdups [(5,5),(5,5),(1,9),(4,6),(5,5),(5,5)]
```

[(5,5),(1,9),(4,6)]

Or

```
rmdups "abcabcdefdef" OR "abcdefabcdef"
```

"abcdef"